# Trying to include previous trading day into subset of data using input date range

Tags: python, dataframe, finance

I am trying to put together a function that will create a subset of data where the input parameters are the data frame, starting date, and ending date.  The first row I would like to see though is the previous trading day of the starting date. For ex. pulling from df, I input starting date = 2018-01-02 and end date = 2018-09-28, but the first row of data I want to see is 2017-12-29 (last day markets were open).  I have this which works, but was wondering if there was a better way to doing it.

```
start_dt = "2018-01-02"
end_dt = "2018-09-28"
train_data_price = None

def getRange(df, start_dt, end_dt):

    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
    from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay

    date_obj = datetime.strptime(start_dt, '%Y-%m-%d')
    US_BUSINESS_DAY = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar()) 
    newdate = date_obj - US_BUSINESS_DAY 
    newdate_str = newdate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') 
    sub_data = data.loc[newdate_str:end_dt] 

return sub_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do so, without needing to know by advance what is the Price-evious candle.

Construction of a dataframe for the example :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dates = pd.date_range("1983-09-01 00:00:00","1985-12-31 23:59:59",freq="1m")
df = pd.DataFrame(index =dates,columns=["Close"])
df['Close'] = [0.183673,0.193673,0.173673,0.163673,0.193673,0.183673,0.16555,0.1993673,0.1282758,0.132758,1.1482758,0.482758,0.482758,0.482758,0.482758,0.482758,1.700000,1.700000,1.700000,1.700000,1.700000,1.700000,1.700000,1.700000,1.700000,1.700000,1.700000,1.700000]
```

And the the code to solve it

```
# you want to start one period before start
start = '1984-01-31'
# end there
end = '1984-08-31'
# Using a mask with np.where is a very fast method
# First flag to 1 the period
df['Mask'] = np.where(((df.index>=start)&(df.index<=end)),1,0)
# then flag to 1 a candle before
df['Mask']  = np.where(df.Mask<df.Mask.shift(-1),1,df.Mask)
# filter where flag == 1
sub_df = df[df.Mask==1].drop(['Mask'],axis=1)
# drop everything useless
df = df.drop(['Mask'],axis=1)
sub_df
```

OUTPUT :

[image]